# C, can not read input

Tags: c, input, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

   int i,j;//count
   int c;//for EOF test
   int menu;
   unsigned int firstSize = 12811;
   unsigned int lastSize;
   char * text=malloc(firstSize);

   if(text == NULL){
        printf("\n Error. no Allocation.");
        exit(-1);
   }
printf("\n for input 1e,for autoinput press 2.");
scanf("%d",&menu);


if(menu==1){
   printf("enter text..");

   c = EOF;
   i = 0;
   lastSize = firstSize;

    while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        text[i++]=(char)c;

        //if i reached maximize size then realloc size
        if(i == lastSize)
        {
                        lastSize = i+firstSize;
            text = realloc(text, lastSize);
        }
    }
```

This is the part of code which is where the problem lies.

Output when I type `1` for the `scanf` is:

```
for input 1e,for autoinput press 2.
1
enter text..
```

It does not let me to give input for the `getchar()`.

But when I delete `scanf` for `menu` and use `menu=1;`, I can easily give input for the `getchar()` and it gives me output correctly:

```
printf("\n for input 1e,for autoinput press 2.");
scanf("%d",&menu);
```

instead of that

```
printf("\n for input 1e,for autoinput press 2.");
//scanf("%d",&menu);
menu=1;
```

Is it about `printf` `scanf` issues that I don't know about? In java, before taking second input, we need to put some blank. Is it like that?

Comment: Post the code *with* the scanf that gives the problem. Align the code please.

Comment: Do you know what is the problem in this Java code: `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); String str1 = input.nextLine(); String str2 = input.nextLine();`? If so, this is the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering a number for your `scanf`. The number is consumed by the `scanf` while the newline character generated by the enter key press resides in the standard input stream(`stdin`).

When the execution of the program reaches the `while` loop:

```
while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

`getchar()` sees the newline character, grabs it, assigns it to `c` and then, the loop doesn't execute as the condition(`c != '\n'`) is false. This is what you were unexpecting.

---

You can add

```
while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

anywhere between the `scanf` and your `getchar()` to clear the `stdin`.

An alternative way would be to use `scanf("%d%*c",&menu);` as suggested by [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219776/c-can-not-read-input/31220044#comment50439944_31219776). `%*c` instructs `scanf` to read and discard a character. It will discard the newline character if the user had typed in a number and then pressed enter for the `scanf`.

---

Other stuff:

`c = EOF;` isn't required. Neither is the cast here: `text[i++]=(char)c;`. You also do not need two variables `lastSize` and `firstSize`. You should also check the return value of `realloc`.

Comment: I need to allocate a first size to initial array. Without allocating, i cant assign variables to array.

Comment: @CursedChico Yes. You need just one variable. Why two? Remove `lastSize` and change `lastSize = i+firstSize;` to `firstSize = i+firstSize;` or `firstSize = firstSize*2;`